# Splash for Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, silverlight, splash-screen

I have an aspx page wherein there are different silverlight components. Each component is of different size and the xaps take different time to download.

Is there any way wherein I can be notified that all my components are downloaded?

I want to display a Splash screen till that time.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to set an event handler to the "loaded" event of the Silverlight plugin as described [here](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/26231/90315.aspx), pointing to a common function that knows each Silverlight plugin on the page and fires another event if all plugins have reported that they are loaded (to hide the splash screen).

But this requires some real-world testing to make sure that the event described there is fired if the plugin is loaded including your "payload" application (and not just the browser plugin).

Another approach could be to implement the "Loaded" event in each of the user controls that make up your applications (maybe by providing a suitable base class) and then invoke a JavaScript method in the surrounding web page as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221359%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), setting a flag for each plugin in the page and hiding the splash screen if all plugins/applications reported to be loaded.